# How to find equal gcd for polynomials?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

In one of my previous questions for finding a value n so that the fraction isn't in the simplest form, the answer stated that $\gcd(2x+5,3x+4) = \gcd(2x+5,x−1)$.

Can anyone explain how the answerer (who I'm very thankful to) arrived at this?

Thank you!

Comment: $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b-a)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The greatest common divisor of the leading coefficients of both expressions, that is, $\gcd (3,2)=1$.

So, $$3x+4-(1)(2x+5) = x-1$$ This is called the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#GCD_by_hand_computation). Hope it helps.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for editing.